# Python - Restarting an if statement if an incorrect value is entered

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

so I am currently learning how to use Python and have been trying to solve a problem of mine where I have an if statement that when an incorrect value is entered I would like it to restart and ask the question again.

I believe a while loop or a for loop will be needed for this however after looking for a while I m just not sure how I would implement it in with this code, therefore if anyone knows I would love to see how.

```
x = int(input("Pick between 1,2,3,4,5: "))

if x == 1:
    print("You picked 1")
elif x == 2:
    print("You picked 2")
elif x == 3:
    print("You picked 3")
elif x == 4:
    print("You picked 4")
elif x == 5:
    print("You picked 5")
else:
    print("This is not a valid input, please try again")
    #Want to go back to asking the start question again
```

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: You need to use a while loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`while` loop is what you need to use in your case:

```
x = int(input("Pick between 1,2,3,4,5: "))

while x not in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    print("This is not a valid input, please try again")
    x = int(input("Pick between 1,2,3,4,5: "))
print("You picked {}".format(x))
```

We check if `x` is not in the list of numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then we ask the user to enter again a number.

If the condition is not `True` (means x is now in the list), then we show the entered number to the user.

Comment: You can also do `while x not in range(1, 6)`.

Comment: Of course, Just want to be more explicit as the OP has already mentioned this sequence.